# Mysql using in Cocoa

Tags: mysql, cocoa

Dear community. The code bellow compiled fine, start, but return empty array. Same code with same base return well. May somebody suggest something?

```
-(NSArray *) mysqlDirectQuery:(NSString *)query
{
// query doesn't using now
NSMutableArray *rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

MYSQL *sql = mysql_init( NULL );
//mysql_options(sql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "LibMySQL");
sql = mysql_real_connect(sql, "localhost", "root", "", "test2", 3306, NULL, 0);
if (sql != NULL) {
    mysql_query(sql, "select * from Users");        
    MYSQL_RES *qResult = mysql_store_result(sql);
    if (qResult != NULL) {
        MYSQL_ROW row;
        while (row == mysql_fetch_row(qResult)) {
                [rows addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSString stringWithCString:row[0] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding],
                                 nil]];
        }
        mysql_free_result(qResult);
    }
    mysql_close(sql);
    mysql_server_end();
}
NSArray *resultArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:rows];
rows = nil;
return resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this:

```
while (row == mysql_fetch_row(qResult))
```

be

```
while (row = mysql_fetch_row(qResult))
```

You are using row[0] below, but you are not assigning it.

Comment: This was product a warning: Semantic Issue: Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses

Comment: You can silence the warning by writing while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(qResult)) != null).